# Unix - grep multiple keywords from a file

Tags: unix, grep, egrep

I have a script that will search for a keyword in all the log files.  It work just fine.

```
LOG_FILES={ "/Sandbox/logs/*" }

for file in ${LOG_FILES[@]}; do
   grep $1 $file
done
```

This only works for 1 keyword.  What if I want to search for more then 1 keywords, say 4 or maybe even 10 keywords.

So I would enter:

```
./myfile.sh 120.2.1.1 Chrome 400 POST
```

It would check for the IP address, chrome, 400 and POST keywords in all the log files.  I see on the internet, they have something like this:

```
egrep 'A1|A2|A3' filename
```

This specify that it will grep the output that is either A1 or A2 or A3 but I would like to grep the output if it is A1 AND A2 AND A3.  I'm not sure how to go about doing this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

tks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to use a sequence of `grep` calls:-

```
grep 'A1' filename | grep 'A2' | grep 'A3'
```

In order to handle an independent number of parameters you will need to build a run string:-

```
str="cat filename"
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do a="$a|grep '$1'"; shift; done
eval "$a"
```

While I generally avoid unnecessary `cat` calls (sorry about the pun), its use in this instance greatly simplifies the script. I haven't tested all combinations with embedded spaces in the parameters, but the above script seems to handle the quoting correctly in simple cases.